# Let $G$ be a finite group, $|G|=pn$ ($p$ is prime). Prove $G$ has a subgroup of order $p$.without using class equation and conjugacy class

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

My textbook indicates that mathematical induction should be used for n, and the hint says consider normalizer.
I know that using sylow's theorem can quickly solve this problem, but I want to know if it can be solved using mathematical induction because I encountered a problem halfway through my proof.
**I'm looking for a solution without using the class equation and some properties about conjugacy class, because in my textbook class equations and conjugacy class are not mentioned in the chapter where this question appears.**
Here is the proof I wrote halfway through.
When n=1, |G|=p, then G is a cyclic group. Hence the propsition holds for n=1. 
Now assume that the propsition holds for group of order kp (1≤k<n). 
Take any non-identity element g in G, let =S. If p | |g|, let |g|=pt. Then $|g^{t}|$=p, the propsition holds.
If p ∤ |a| , note |g| = m>1. Let the normalizer of S be N(S). N(S)={a|a ∈ G, aS=Sa}. N(S) is a subgroup of G. Since =S and S is a subgroup of G. Hence S is a normal subgroup of N(S). By Lagrange's theorem, |N(S)|·(G:N(S))=np, hence p||N(S)| or p|(G:N(S)).
If p | |N(S)|,consider the case that N(S)=G, then S is a normal subgroup of G.|G/S|=$\frac{np}{m}$.By assumption, G/S has a element of order p. Take any element bS $\in$ G/S, let |b|=r, then $b^{r}S$=S, hence p | r. Let r=pt, then $|b^{t}|$=p.
Now consider N(S)<G, let N(S)=kp. By assumption, there is a subgroup of order p in N(S).
If p | (G:N(S)), Now I'm stuck here.

Comment: Can you post some of your work?  Especially where you're getting stuck.  That would help anyone attempting to answer to give a more meaningful response.

Comment: This is just Cauchy's Theorem. Search the site for `Cauchy's Theorem`, `[group-theory]`, and `induction`

Comment: @abissu Sure. When n=1,  |G|=p, then G is a cyclic group. Hence the propsition holds for n=1. Now assume that the propsition holds for group of order kp (1 $\leq$ k<n). Take any non-identity element g in G, let <g>=S. If p | |g|, let |g|=pt. Then |$g^{t}$|=p, the propsition holds. If p $\nmid$ |a| , note |g| = m>1. Let the normalizer of S be N(S). N(S)={a|a $\in$ G, aS=Sa}. N(S) is a subgroup of G. Since <g>=S, S is a subgroup of G. Hence S is a normal subgroup of N(S). If p | |N(S)|, I can prove that the conclusion holds, but I don't know how to proof the situation when p | (G:N(S)).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, thanks for your comment, but I'm looking for a solution without using the class equation and some properties about conjugacy class,  because in my textbook class equations and conjugacy class are not mentioned in the chapter where this question appears.

Comment: Point the first: Should people know that without reading your mind? Nothing in your post puts those restrictions; you only ask that it be done with induction. If you don't give the context, then you should not object to answers that do not meet your *completely unspoken* requirements. Point the Second: I did not give you a solution, I told you how to search the site to find one. I did not even vote to close, so why are you complaining at me?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm sorry for my incomplete question, and I'm very sorry for you, my English is not good, it may have caused you some misunderstanding, I didn't mean to complain about you.

Comment: "I am very sorry for you" does not mean you apologize to me; it would normally be understood as you taking pity on me, which is unlikely what you meant. I let you know this so you do not use the expression that way in the future.